# How can we upload multiple document files on Google Drive API

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I want to upload multiple document Files (ex. PDF, Text etc.) I am able to upload the single file to drive. below is my code for Single File upload to drive. I have used Document Picker Controller.

```
public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {


    if let documentsDir = url as URL? {

        print("import result : \(documentsDir)")

        let indexFileName = (documentsDir.pathComponents.last)!
        print("THE FILE NAME", indexFileName)

        let testFilePath = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent("").path

        drive?.uploadFile("FolderNameOnDrive", filePath: testFilePath, MIMEType: "image/pdf") { (fileID, error) in
            print("Upload file ID: \(String(describing: fileID)); Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

            print("THE FILE ID IS",fileID ?? "")
            print("The test File Path", testFilePath)
        }
    }

}
```

The testFilePath is the document path from the document directory that enable the user to select the file.

I have enable the `documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true`. But still stuck in multiple upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just upload by one and use a `DispatchGroup` to get completion when all files uploaded:

```
struct File {
        let name: String
        let path: URL
        let MIMEType: String
    }

let uploadGroup = DispatchGroup()
var drives = [Drive]()

func upload(files: [File], completion: () -> Void){
    let drive = Drive()
    drives.append(drive)
    for file in files {
        uploadGroup.enter()
        drive.uploadFile(file.name, filePath: file.path, MIMEType: file.MIMEType) { (fileID, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error: \(error)")
                uploadGroup.leave()
            }

            print("uploaded: \(fileID)")
            uploadGroup.leave()
        }
    }

        uploadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            completion()
        }
}
```

P.S. But you need to remake your uploader class for multiple uploads or create new instance for every upload like in my example

Comment: Thanks That helped me too. Now its working... :) Thanks again Brother

Answer (score 0):

Override `didPickDocumentsAt` instead of `didPickDocumentAt`. Note the plural.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Sir, That helped Me. have a nice Day :)